# Jquery two descendents of the same parent in the selector

Tags: jquery

Couldn't find in the doc how to specify several children of the same parent.
For example,

```
$('.father > child1, child2')
```

Jquery interprets this as "select child2 (no matter if it's parent is father or not)and father's child1. Whereas I mean "select father's child1 and child2)

Comment: have you use `.children()` selector ? something like `$('.father').children();`

Comment: Use the selectors as in CSS direclty.

Answer (score 1):

Either have to use `.father` for both css selectors or use `children()` or `find()`

```
$('.father > child1, .father > child2')
```

Or

```
$('.father').children('.child1, .child2')
```

Or

```
$('.father').find('> .child1, > .child2')
```

Comment: Is the unary usage of `>` within jQuery clearly defined and documented?

Comment: or `$('> .child1, > .child2', '.father')`. *:D*